# Rolling deploy with CachedFilesMixin + S3

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, memcached, django-staticfiles

We use S3Storage with the CachedFilesMixin and the static template tag to serve up our files from Cloud Front. When packaging our app we run collect static to generate hashes and sync files to S3. It works quite well. But there is an issue that concerns me.

The issue arrises because we do rolling upgrades. This creates 2 forms of inconsistency as we rol out a new version of the app:

1) Before we call collectstatic/clear cache, any servers running new code will not see the new assets they expect. 
2) After calling collectsstatic/clear cache, any servers running old code we see new assets it doesn't expect.

I am contemplating a couple options and was just curious if anybody had already solved this problem or had feedback.

1) Remove CachedFilesMixin and add the app "version" as location to S3Storage. This would essentially "version" the assets. The drawback here is that we loose the high level of caching and users have to re-download files every time we deploy the app

2) Extend CacheFilesMixin and provide the ability to calculate the hash based on a "versioned" file. After calling collect static I would upload the current unhashed files to a version folder on S3.  CachedFilesMixin would pull the file from the version folder to calculate the hash.

EDIT: 9/17/2014 - 3rd Option (with is currently my favorite)

3) Override our storage class so that "open" will read from local disc. Update the cache to use local memory cache. This means when there is a cache miss it will has the local file on disc.

EDIT: 9/18/2014 - FOUND SOLUTION

I ended up getting #3 to work, although slightly different than the original idea. Here are the steps I took.

1) Removed S3Storage to simply things
2) Crated a new Storage class that subclasses StaticFileStorage and overrides url to provide a cloud front url.

```
class LocalStorageWithCloudFrontUrl(StaticFilesStorage):

    # This url is on the super class so that mix can fire first to provide the hash name functionality..
    def url(self, name, *args, **kwargs):
       return 'https://{0}/{1}'.format(STATIC_DOMAIN, name)
```

3) My storage class now inherits from this new class

```
class StaticStorage(PipelineMixin, CachedFilesMixin, LocalStorageWithCloudFrontUrl):
```

4) Updated my cache to be a local in memory cache

```
'staticfiles': {
    'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
    'LOCATION': 'staticfiles-filehashes'
}
```

5) In my test & package job I call collect static and then call aws sync to push the hashed files to S3.

6) Now S3 will contain all the hashed version as before, as well as the latest build's unhashed files, but these are never used because the CachhedFilesMixin will use the files on the local files system to generate the hashes.

It would be nice if collect static would push to S3 but otherwise this seems to work really well.